# Ownerdraw TListBox child controls are not moved by scrolling

Tags: delphi, tlistbox

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  inherited;
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left+5, Rect.Top+8, TListBox(Control).Items[Index]);
  if odSelected in State then
  begin
    Button.Left:=Rect.Right-80;
    Button.Top:=Rect.Top+4;
    Button.Visible:=true;
    Button.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.DoubleBuffered:=true;
  ListBox1.ItemHeight:=30;
  ListBox1.Style:=lbOwnerDrawFixed;
  Button:=TButton.Create(ListBox1);
  Button.Parent:=ListBox1;
  Button.DoubleBuffered:=true;
  Button.Visible:=false;
  Button.Width:=50;
  Button.Height:=20;
  Button.Caption:='BTN';
end;
```

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

The repaint problem only exists when using ScrollBar or sending WM_VSCROLL message to my ListBox. All normally drawn when I change selection by using keyboard arrows or mouse clicks. Problem also not exists when selected item are visible by scrolling and not leave visible area.

I think that Button.Top property still have an old value before DrawItem calls, and change (to -30px for example) later.

Comment: TListBox haven't OnScroll event. Message WM_VSCROLL can be catched only in overriden windpoc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `OnDrawItem` event to make changes to the UI (in this case, positioning the button).  Do not do that, the event is for DRAWING ONLY.

I would suggest that you either:

1. subclass the ListBox to handle the `WM_VSCROLL` message and have your message handler reposition the button as needed.

   ```
   var
     PrevListBoxWndProc: TWndMethod;

   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     PrevListBoxWndProc := ListBox1.WindowProc;
     ListBox1.WindowProc := ListBoxWndProc;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     ListBox1.WindowProc := PrevListBoxWndProc;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.PositionButton(Index: Integer);
   var
     R: TRect;
   begin
     if Index <= -1 then
       Button.Visible := False
     else
     begin 
       R := ListBox1.ItemRect(Index);
       Button.Left := R.Right - 80;
       Button.Top := R.Top + 4;
       Button.Visible := True;
     end;
   end;

   var
     LastIndex: Integer = -1;

   procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
     Index: Integer;
   begin
     Index := ListBox1.ItemIndex;
     if Index <> LastIndex then
     begin
       LastIndex := Index;
       PositionButton(Index);
     end;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.ListBoxWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
   begin
     PrevListBoxWndProc(Message);
     if Message.Msg = WM_VSCROLL then
       PositionButton(ListBox1.ItemIndex);
   end;
   ```
2. get rid of the `TButton` altogether. Use `OnDrawItem` to draw an *image* of a button (you can use [`DrawFrameControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480.aspx) or [`DrawThemeBackground()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx) for that) directly onto the ListBox, and then use the `OnMouseDown/Up` or `OnClick` event to check if the mouse is over the "button" and if so act accordingly as needed.

   ```
   var
     MouseX: Integer = -1;
     MouseY: Integer = -1;

   procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
       Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
   var
     R: TRect;
     P: TPoint;
     BtnState: UINT;
   begin
     TListBox(Control).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
     TListBox(Control).Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left+5, Rect.Top+8, TListBox(Control).Items[Index]);
     if not (odSelected in State) then Exit;
     R := Rect(Rect.Right-80, Rect.Top+4, Rect.Right-30, Rect.Top+24);
     P := Point(MouseX, MouseY);
     BtnState := DFCS_BUTTONPUSH;
     if PtInRect(R, P) then BtnState := BtnState or DFCS_PUSHED;
     DrawFrameControl(TListBox(Control).Canvas.Handle, R, DFC_BUTTON, BtnState);
     InflateRect(R, -4, -4);
     DrawText(TListBox(Control).Canvas.Handle, 'BTN', 3, R, DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER or DT_SINGLELINE);
   end;

   procedure TForm1.ListBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
     Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
   begin
     if Button <> mbLeft then Exit;
     MouseX := X;
     MouseY := Y;
     ListBox1.Invalidate;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.ListBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
     Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
   begin
     if Button <> mbLeft then Exit;
     MouseX := -1;
     MouseY := -1;
     ListBox1.Invalidate;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
     P: TPoint;
     R: TRect;
     Index: Integer;
   begin
     P := Point(MouseX, MouseY);
     Index := ListBox1.ItemAtPos(P, True);
     if (Index = -1) or (Index <> ListBox1.ItemIndex) then Exit;
     R := ListBox1.ItemRect(Index);
     R := Rect(R.Right-80, R.Top+4, R.Right-30, R.Top+24);
     if not PtInRect(R, P) then Exit;
     // click is on selected item's "button", do something...
   end;
   ```